# Pointwise limit of continuous function sequence

Tags: analysis

Let $f_n, f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n \to f$ converge pointwise.

Is there an example that satisfying the following $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(\frac{1}{n})\neq f(0)$$?? Otherwise, does that equality hold?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you let $f_n(1/n)=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: You said you wanted a hint, if I tell you what $f_n(x)$ is, wouldn't that be giving you the entire answer?  The easiest cases to consider are when everything goes to 0.

Comment: Draw a triangle with vertices at $(0,0), (0\frac 2 n)$ and $(\frac  1 n, 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the zero function and let $f_n$ be defined by:$$f_{n}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
nx & \text{if }x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]\\
2-nx & \text{if }x\in\left[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}\right]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Observe the $f_n(\frac1n)=1$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you are looking for if you assume that the sequence $f_n$ converges **uniformly** to $f$ (this will naturally entail that $f$ is continuous). Otherwise, it is quite easy to construct cases where this doesn't hold.

Take the sequence $f_n = \arctan(nx)$. This sequence converges pointwise to the limit
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac{\pi}{2} & x < 0\\
0 & x = 0\\
\frac{\pi}{2}  & x > 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
However, each element of the sequence $f_n(\frac{1}{n})$ is $\arctan(1)$, so manifestly $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(\frac{1}{n}) \neq f(0)$.